# Changed column name to upper case when create a new table through script in Oracle how to resolve this?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle tool (Oracle SQL Developer -  Version 19.2.1.247).
When i create new table in Oracle Db then it change all column name in uppercase i.e.(CUSTOMERID), but i want to keep column name i.e.(CustomerId).I am looking for solutions how to resolve this.

I did some try to change formatting of editor as well code setting in Tools -> Preference but not found any proper things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " i want to keep column name i.e.(CustomerId)"    No, you don't.  As others have said, Oracle _defaults_ to storing names as upper-case, then treating them as case-INsensitive.  If you force case sensitivity, then you will always have to remember to dobule-quote with the correct case and that quickly becomes a PITA..  Take off your MS goggles.  In the oracle world, the normal practice to make object names more readable, instead of MixedCaseNames, use underscore_delimited_names.

Comment: While Oracle convert object names to uppercase it is case insensitive on there usage. Thus you can use MixedCaseNames in your queries and pl/sql for readability (if you actually think that helps). You just have to keep that in mind when looking at messages and find MIXEDCASENAMES. BTW converting to uppercase is the SQL Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid doing that. Every object ( table, column, index, sequence, trigger... ) is stored in uppercase in the Oracle dictionary.

However, if you want to store the name in lowercase, you must use double quotation

```
SQL> create table test ( c1 number );

Table created

SQL> select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TEST';

COLUMN_NAME
C1

SQL> create table test ( "c1" number );

Table created

SQL> select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TEST';

COLUMN_NAME
c1
```

Keep in mind that if you store the value in lowercase, any search or program that uses the dictionary will have to take this in consideration. That is why I believe it is not a good practice.

Comment: Thank you - Roberto

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a default functionality where it will convert all unquoted table/column identifiers to upper case, therefore add double quotes around the names should resolve your issue.